# can we count the upload filesize before uploading in python-flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple flask app where i am uploading single file but with file size of less than 5MB

 for that i have defined 
`if request.content_length < 5.250e+6: ## setting upload limit to 5MB` test case in my flask-app; but this is verifying the file size after uploading it; or may be i am wrong. 
so is there any way to get the file size before uploading it???

Here is python [solution](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/master/server/gae-python) on python+GAE, but i am new to python web framework; i know very little in flask
 and this solution is based on webapp2 which is very complicated for me and also its on GAE; that is another story.
so can anyone generate its `flask` equivalent or any other possible way to do it in `flask`???

Answer (score 5):

Flask is able to limit file size while upload is in progress, see the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/#improving-uploads).  All you need is to set `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` when configuring your app.

Comment: this too is verifying file size after file upload.. .i want that should be before upload.
In my question i have mentioned a solution(https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/master/server/gae-python) but that is using `webapp2` which i don't know; and `flask` is new for me; so can that be converted into `flask`??

Comment: No, it does abort the request with `413 REQUEST ENTITY TOO LARGE` immediately after it sees Content-Length value which is larger than `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` you've set. I just tested it with curl, and it works as expected. Note that for file uploads your form must be encoded as `multipart/form-data`. If it's missing, perhaps that's why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: can i handle it with `error handler` (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler).

Comment: i mean that `413` error; where i will show the error msg as 'file upload limit is 5MB'

Comment: Sure, just provide that error code: `@app.errorhandler(413) ...`

Comment: Kind of running into the same problem. Looking at Werkzeug's FormParser code, it looks like Werkzeug honours that setting of MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH only if the request contains Content-Length header. That means, if your browser uses chunked-encoding then it is unlikely to work because Content-Length won't be found in the headers.

Comment: The problem here is that WSGI specification doesn't support chunked-encoding requests, see: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/367

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit expanded version of Audrius Kažukauskas's answer:

---

> so is there any way to get the file size before uploading it???

**No**. 
As per [werkzeug's documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest._get_file_stream) that `Flask` use to handle uploaded file, you cannot verify the content-size before uploading is NOT guaranteed by all browsers. Only the total content-length of all the data in the `request` is guaranteed to be there. web-browsers. Hence, Flask/werkzeug can enforce checking only after file-upload.

However, to avoid crashing of your web-server from memory-overflow, you can and should limit the upload-able size. Here comes the config variable `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH`which you can mention in app's config file.

Example usage from [Flask doc](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/docs/patterns/fileuploads.rst#improving-uploads):

> ```
> from flask import Flask, Request
>
> app = Flask(__name__)
> app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024  # for 16MB max-limit.
> ```

However, for any serious application, you should consider using the Flask-plugin [Flask-Uploads](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/) which allows more advanced options such as white-listing and black-listing certain file-types, type-based upload rules, configurable upload destinations etc.

You can question ***why should i go for the extra extension***.
Because, `Flask` is a micro-framework. Not a do-it-all framework.