# Cannot upload files bigger than 1MB from JavaScript to Flask

Tags: javascript, flask

When I select small files there is no problem. But for big files larger than around 1MB I get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` on Chromium or `NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource` on Firefox console and `308` status code on server, whether I use the production server or Gunicorn. Any solution?

JavaScript:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append("file", inputFile.files[0]);
let response = await fetch("/upload?key=value", {method: "PUT", body: data});
```

Python:

```
@app.put('/upload/')
def upload_file():
    key = request.args['key']
    file = request.files['file']
    print(key)
    print(file)
    return ''
```

**EDIT:** I found the problem. The problem is the query string. The following codes work. Now I want to know how can I pass the query string using PUT or POST method to Flask?

New JavaScript:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append("file", inputFile.files[0]);
let response = await fetch("/upload/", {method: "PUT", body: data});
```

New Python:

```
@app.put('/upload/')
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['file']
    print(file)
    return ''
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask file upload limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911106/flask-file-upload-limit)

Comment: I tried it. Does nothing.

Comment: do you have control on upload_max_filesize  in your server's configuration, you need to increase it

Comment: @TahaAzzabi By default Flask will happily accept file uploads with an unlimited amount of memory. Source: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Here is the solution. Just watch out for slashes:

JavaScript code:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append("file", inputFile.files[0]);
let response = await fetch("/upload?key=value", {method: "PUT", body: data});
```

Python code:

```
@app.put('/upload') # no slash at the end
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['file']
    value = request.args['key']
    print(file)
    print(value)
    return ''
```

But I do not know why.